# Can't save compressed file to temporary storage Android

Tags: android, file, compression, fileoutputstream, internal-storage

I have some code to create a temporary file to save a compressed image file to it before sending it out to the server.  The image gets to the server and is saved. The problem is that the file is 0 kB and I'm sure the compression isn't that good. It looks like the file isn't getting saved to the `fileOutputStream`, but after reading the documentation and examples, I'm not seeing why not. Also, the bitmap has 8294400 bytes and the saved file has a length of 0. That's why I think something happens while being sent out on `fileOutputStream`.

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) profileImage.getDrawable();
Bitmap bmap = drawable.getBitmap();

String filename = "tempImage";
File file = null;
try {;
        file = File.createTempFile(filename, null,   getApplicationContext().getCacheDir());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

FileOutputStream fout = null;
try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    fout = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE);
    bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fout);
    fout.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: First, replace `fout.close();` with `fout.flush(); fout.getFd().sync(); fout.close();`, to ensure all bytes get committed to disk before proceeding. Beyond that, how *exactly* are you determining "the saved file has a length of 0"? Are you using **`adb shell`**? The file manager in the Android Device Monitor? Your desktop operating system's file manager? Something else?

Comment: The file is saved on my server's file system and I can see that it is 0.  I will make the changes and let you know the result.  Thanks.

Comment: before it's saved to the server and when it's just saved temporarily, I'm also reading the length of the file in internal storage with file.length().  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: "before it's saved I'm also reading the length of the file in internal storage with file.length()" -- well, by definition, the file has zero length before you write to it. Check the length of the file using **`adb shell`** after writing to it, to see if the problem is in the writing or in the uploading.

Comment: I did the changes there is no change in output.  I updated my comment.  I meant that I check the length after it's saved to the file.  The next line in the code is:  Log.i("length", Long.toString( file.length()));

Comment: Ok so I did get it to save. Apparently the issue was "fout = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE);"  I need to figure out why that caused the issue though.  At any rate, the compressed file is twice as big, so there's still an issue with this method.  If you happen to know what's going on let me know. But looks like I'll be scratching my head for a while.